# Regex to match json in python

Tags: python, regex

iam unable to get json object from string in python. i need to get items: from response text. i have tried,

```
[items?:?]\s(\".*\")

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(BoxedLinksListView, {
            initialState: {
                items: [{
                    link: "https://www.sehir.edu.tr/en/academics/college-of-humanities-and-social-sciences",
                    sort: 1,
                    parentTitle: "",
                    title: "College of Humanities and Social Sciences"
                }, {
                    link: "https://www.sehir.edu.tr/en/academics/graduate-school-of-business/mba-in-islamic-finance-and-economics",
                    sort: 82,
                    parentTitle: "Graduate School of Business",
                    title: "MBA in Islamic Finance and Economics (Thesis)"
                }, {
                    link: "https://www.sehir.edu.tr/en/academics/graduate-school-of-business/mba-in-islamic-finance-and-economics",
                    sort: 83,
                    parentTitle: "Graduate School of Business",
                    title: "MBA in Islamic Finance and Economics (Non-thesis)"
                }]
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please use a JSON parser to handle JSON content, not a regex.

Comment: above is string, i need to match regex for items. were i can grab items list and then covert to json.

Comment: As already mentioned, don't do that! Use a [json parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) for that! Afterwards you can do whatever you want with that values.

Comment: regex is not capable of flow control, it cannot find matching brackets. Or maybe no one is understanding your question, in that case you should be more clear on what you want

Comment: stop talking about json parser! The given text/format is NOT valid in JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **Regex** & **Json** module.

**Demo:**

```
import re
import json
s = """ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(BoxedLinksListView, {
            initialState: {
                items: [{
                    link: "https://www.sehir.edu.tr/en/academics/college-of-humanities-and-social-sciences",
                    sort: 1,
                    parentTitle: "",
                    title: "College of Humanities and Social Sciences"
                }, {
                    link: "https://www.sehir.edu.tr/en/academics/graduate-school-of-business/mba-in-islamic-finance-and-economics",
                    sort: 82,
                    parentTitle: "Graduate School of Business",
                    title: "MBA in Islamic Finance and Economics (Thesis)"
                }, {
                    link: "https://www.sehir.edu.tr/en/academics/graduate-school-of-business/mba-in-islamic-finance-and-economics",
                    sort: 83,
                    parentTitle: "Graduate School of Business",
                    title: "MBA in Islamic Finance and Economics (Non-thesis)"
                }]
            }
        }"""

data = re.findall(r"items\:\s+.*\]", s, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)[0]
data = "{" + re.sub("([a-zA-Z]+)\:", r'"\1":', data).replace('""https"', '"https') + "}"
print (json.loads(data))
```

**Output:**

```
{u'items': [{u'sort': 1, u'parentTitle': u'', u'link': u'https://www.sehir.edu.tr/en/academics/college-of-humanities-and-social-sciences', u'title': u'College of Humanities and Social Sciences'}, {u'sort': 82, u'parentTitle': u'Graduate School of Business', u'link': u'https://www.sehir.edu.tr/en/academics/graduate-school-of-business/mba-in-islamic-finance-and-economics', u'title': u'MBA in Islamic Finance and Economics (Thesis)'}, {u'sort': 83, u'parentTitle': u'Graduate School of Business', u'link': u'https://www.sehir.edu.tr/en/academics/graduate-school-of-business/mba-in-islamic-finance-and-economics', u'title': u'MBA in Islamic Finance and Economics (Non-thesis)'}]}
```

Comment: can u access the link?

Comment: No, I cannot access the link

Comment: can u please help me in this.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot access any of the link you have mentioned in the comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171160/discussion-between-cdon-and-rakesh).

Comment: Dude. Can you post your data in the Question? Because I have very limited access to the internet...or else I will try to help you after I reach my home

Comment: Try `data = re.findall(r"items\:\s+.*?\]", s, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)[0]`